# How can you create a UITextView that displays strings from an array in response to any keys being typed by the user (in a Swift Playground in Xcode)?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I'm creating a hacker simulator in Swift Playgrounds. I have an array of 100 strings/elements that are randomly picked with GKRandomSource method.

What method can I use to display these strings (one at a time) when the user presses any key on their keyboard?

Example of a hacker simulator - http://hackertyper.com/

Comment: You are looking for `UITextViewDelegate` methods. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate

Comment: If i am not wrong, You need like For Eg. If user open keyboard and then click on some character and once it taps the random string is generated and then you get a string and then display it.?